# PHP code to find the second highest number taking user input from an html form

Tags: php, html, web

It may be a silly question but I recently started to learn PHP and have to write a code to be able to find the second highest number entered in 5 text boxes in a form and am not able to get the code to work even for just comparing 3 numbers, I've used the "if" statement but it keeps going to the "else"

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way to do it, you put answers into an array, you sort it, and pick the before last index value like this.

```
<?php

$answer1 = 500;
$answer2 = 15;
$answer3 = 50;
$answer4 = 5;
$answer5 = 122;

$myArray = [$answer1, $answer2, $answer3, $answer4, $answer5];

sort($myArray);

echo $myArray[count($myArray)-2];

?>
```

Ouput:

```
122
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it without the use of array's and using if statements ?